# How do I compute an averaged profile in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I call an average profile the 1D signal obtained by averaging along the rows or columns in a rectangular image.

```
Px := Σ(y=1,H) I(x, y) / H
```

and

```
Py := Σ(x=1,W) I(x, y) / W
```

I couldn't find that in the API, maybe by not using the appropriate terminology.

I don't want a box filter, just one value per row/column. The sum instead of the average is equally good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the reduce function: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce

```
using namespace cv;

// Average over rows
Mat mean_over_rows; 
reduce(input_mat, mean_over_rows, 0, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
// Average over the columns
Mat mean_over_cols;
reduce(input_mat, mean_over_cols, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
```

You can use the `CV_REDUCE_SUM` flag if you just want the summed projection along the desired axes.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. Will the image be seen as a matrix or is a conversion required ?

Comment: I think it has to be an opencv Mat structure.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If it solved your problem, can you also accept the answer please?

Comment: There's a missing link between the image and the Mat.

Comment: You have to convert the image to the OpenCV Mat structure. It is not possible for me to help you with that as I have no idea what data structure your image is stored as. This was not your original question, which mentions nothing bout the image. Anyway.... no worries.

Comment: My image is an OpenCV image.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some code on how this image is loaded. We cannot guess this information.... As far as I know OpenCV Mat class is the image container. I am not aware of any openCV Image class. Please link to the docs. Have you tried using the reduce function with your "image" object?

Comment: Ok, my assumption was based on the use of the Python wrapper, where actually the types aren't documented. You can ignore my previous comments.